Hard Inequalities between harmonic and geometric means
Let's have $0 < \lambda_1 \leq \lambda_2 \leq ... \leq \lambda_n$ $n$ positive numbers
How to show that :
$$\left( \frac{n}{\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_k}} - \lambda_1 \right)^n \leq \prod_{k = 1}^n \lambda_k \leq \left( \frac{n}{\sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{1}{\lambda_n + \lambda_k}} - \lambda_n \right)^n$$
Or equivalently, if $A = \text{Diag}(\lambda_1,... \lambda_n)$ then
$$\left( \frac{n}{Tr((A + \lambda_1 I)^{-1})} - \lambda_1 \right)^n \leq \det(A) \leq \left( \frac{n}{Tr((A + \lambda_n I)^{-1})} - \lambda_n \right)^n$$
I tried to use classical inequalities between means but it does not work. (If I use $HM \leq GM$ the relation $(GM - \lambda_1)^n \leq \det(A)$ is not always satisfied) Any ideas?

We prove the left inequality. The proof of the right inequality is similar (except that $g(x) := \frac{1}{\lambda_n + \mathrm{e}^x}$ is concave on $[0, \ln \lambda_n]$).
Let $\lambda_k = \mathrm{e}^{x_k}, k=2, 3, \cdots, n$. The desired inequality is written as
$$\left( \frac{n}{\frac{1}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_1} + \sum_{k = 2}^n \frac{1}{\lambda_1 + \mathrm{e}^{x_k}}} - \lambda_1 \right)^n \leq  \lambda_1 \mathrm{e}^{x_2 + \cdots + x_n}. $$
Note that $f(x) := \frac{1}{\lambda_1 + \mathrm{e}^x}$ is convex on $[\ln \lambda_1, \infty)$ since $f''(x) = \frac{\mathrm{e}^x(\mathrm{e}^x - \lambda_1)}{(\lambda_1 + \mathrm{e}^x)^3}$. By Jensen's inequality, we have
$$\sum_{k = 2}^n \frac{1}{\lambda_1 + \mathrm{e}^{x_k}}
\ge \frac{n - 1}{\lambda_1 + \mathrm{e}^{(x_2 + \cdots + x_n)/(n-1)}}.$$
Thus, it suffices to prove that
$$\left( \frac{n}{\frac{1}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_1} + \frac{n - 1}{\lambda_1 + \mathrm{e}^{(x_2 + \cdots + x_n)/(n-1)}}} - \lambda_1 \right)^n \leq  \lambda_1 \mathrm{e}^{x_2 + \cdots + x_n}, $$
or (letting $y := \mathrm{e}^{(x_2 + \cdots + x_n)/(n-1)} \ge \lambda_1$)
$$\left( \frac{n}{\frac{1}{\lambda_1 + \lambda_1} + \frac{n - 1}{\lambda_1 + y}} - \lambda_1 \right)^n \leq  \lambda_1 y^{n-1}, $$
or (letting $z := y/\lambda_1 \ge 1$)
$$\left( \frac{n}{\frac{1}{1 + 1} + \frac{n - 1}{1 + z}} - 1 \right)^n \leq   z^{n-1}, $$
or
$$F(z) := (n-1)\ln z - n\ln\left( \frac{n}{\frac{1}{1 + 1} + \frac{n - 1}{1 + z}} - 1 \right) \ge 0. $$
We have
$$F'(z) = \frac{(n-1)(1-z)^2(2n-1)}{z(2nz - z + 1)(2n+z -1)}\ge 0.$$
Also, $F(1) = 0$. Thus, $F(z) \ge 0$ on $z \ge 1$.
We are done.
